# The Discord bot that checks users' online time is not working

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to make a discord bot which, after entering the >time_online command, will show how much the user has been online, but it keeps throwing the error "Could not find member polandlp on this server" even if I am online and the bot has all the permissions, what did I do wrong?

CODE:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from datetime import datetime


intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='>', intents=intents)

@bot.command()
async def time_online(ctx):
    user = ctx.author
    guild = ctx.guild

    # Pobierz informacje o stanie użytkownika
    member = guild.get_member(user.id)
    if member:
        if member.status != discord.Status.offline and member.activity is not None:
            # Oblicz czas online
            time_online = datetime.utcnow() - member.activity.start
            minutes_online = time_online.total_seconds() // 60
            await ctx.send(f'{user.name} is online for {minutes_online} minutes.')
        else:
            await ctx.send(f'{user.name} is offline or not currently active.')
    else:
        await ctx.send(f'Could not find member {user.name} on this server.')

@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send('pong')
bot.run("my token")
```

I tryed test all IFs and I see If member: dont work

Comment: You're missing the indent `presences` which is required to get a member status and activity, you should add `intents.presences = True`. More about [this intent here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=intent#discord.Intents.presences)

Comment: When I added this its dont change anything. polandlp is offline or not currently active when i am online

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons why your code doesnt work as expected:

1. First you need the `intents.presences` to be enabled as [Paul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14327609/paul) mentioned as well as `intents.members` (make sure to enable them on the developer portal, too).
2. Now after running your code i get the following error:

`discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: can't subtract offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes`

A fix to this would be to use the `calendar` module to convert the datetime into a unix timestamp which represents the time in seconds since 1. January 1970.
So to get the current time in seconds:

```
date = datetime.utcnow()
currenttime = int(calendar.timegm(date.utctimetuple())) #converting the datetime into a unix timestamp
```

This also applies to the `member.activity()`

```py
int(calendar.timegm(member.activity.start.utctimetuple()))
```

Now when you subtract both of them you get the total seconds of how long you stayed active.

Your code will look like this:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from datetime import datetime
import calendar


intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
intents.presences = True
intents.members = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='>', intents=intents)

@bot.command()
async def time_online(ctx):
        member = ctx.author

        if member.status != discord.Status.offline and member.activity is not None:
            date = datetime.utcnow()
            currenttime = int(calendar.timegm(date.utctimetuple()))
            time_online = currenttime - int(calendar.timegm(member.activity.start.utctimetuple()))
            minutes_online = time_online // 60
            await ctx.send(f'{member.name} is online for {minutes_online} minutes.')
        else:
            await ctx.send(f'{member.name} is offline or not currently active.')

@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send('pong')
bot.run("my token")
```